# Issue with cell reuse in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that displays information but mostly the bit I am stuck on is showing star ratings. I have managed to create a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains the logic to display how man star rating each cell has. So if there is a rating of 3 it will display 3 yellow stars and 2 blank stars so altogether theres a total rating of 5. When the `UITableView` is displayed I can see that the star rating for the first 4 cells is correct:

Display of only TEN cells.

```
Rating in order of cell (what comes back from the Database):
5
3
3
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

but whats happening is that when I scroll the cells I get these ratings, seems to repeat the first for cell rating:

```
Rating in order of cell when scrolled (UI Scrolling):
5
3
3
1
5
3
3
1
5
3
```

Why is this happening?

I will give you code and edit if needed.

### EDIT

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == tableViewTopThreads){

        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        ThreadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        //cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        //cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[ThreadTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        Thread *t = (Thread*)[tmpArray4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.labelTitle.text = t.title;
        cell.labelCat.text = t.cat;
        cell.labelUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", t.firstname, t.lastname];
        cell.labelDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.date];
        cell.labelCountry.text = t.country;
        cell.labelSubCat.text = t.subcat;
        cell.rating = t.rating;

        [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [cell.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
        [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
        [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Custom Cell:

```
        #import "ThreadTableViewCell.h"


        @implementation ThreadTableViewCell

        @synthesize main;
        @synthesize top;
        @synthesize center;
        @synthesize bottom;
        @synthesize rate;
        @synthesize rating;
        @synthesize labelTitle;
        @synthesize labelCat;
        @synthesize labelSubCat;
        @synthesize labelUser;
        @synthesize labelDate;
        @synthesize labelCountry;
        @synthesize imageviewThreadImage;
        @synthesize imageviewRating1;
        @synthesize imageviewRating2;
        @synthesize imageviewRating3;
        @synthesize imageviewRating4;
        @synthesize imageviewRating5;


        - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
            self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            if (self) {

            //self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

            [self.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
            self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

            //CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
            //CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
            //CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
            //CGFloat screenHeight = screenSize.height;

            main = [UIView new];
            [self.contentView addSubview:main];
            main.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            //[main sizeToFit];
            main.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            top = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:top];
            top.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            //[top sizeToFit];
            top.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            labelUser = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelUser];
            labelUser.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            //[labelUser sizeToFit];
            [labelUser setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelUser.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelDate = [UILabel new];
            [top addSubview:labelDate];
            labelDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelDate sizeToFit];
            [labelDate setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelDate.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(114.0/255.0) green:(114.0/255.0) blue:(114.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            center = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:center];
            center.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [center sizeToFit];
            center.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            imageviewThreadImage = [UIImageView new];
            [center addSubview:imageviewThreadImage];
            imageviewThreadImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            imageviewThreadImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(207.0/255.0) green:(215.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelTitle = [UILabel new];
            [center addSubview:labelTitle];
            labelTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelTitle sizeToFit];
            labelTitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            [labelTitle setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
            labelTitle.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            labelTitle.numberOfLines = 0;
            //labelTitle.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = screenWidth - 10 - 36;

            bottom = [UIView new];
            [main addSubview:bottom];
            bottom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [bottom sizeToFit];

            labelCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCat];
            labelCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCat sizeToFit];
            [labelCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelSubCat = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelSubCat];
            labelSubCat.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelSubCat sizeToFit];
            [labelSubCat setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelSubCat.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

            labelCountry = [UILabel new];
            [bottom addSubview:labelCountry];
            labelCountry.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [labelCountry sizeToFit];
            [labelCountry setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
            labelCountry.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(58.0/255.0) green:(82.0/255.0) blue:(207.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];


            rate = [UIView new];
            [bottom addSubview:rate];
            rate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [rate sizeToFit];


            imageviewRating1 = [UIImageView new];
            [rate addSubview:imageviewRating1];
            imageviewRating1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [imageviewRating1 sizeToFit];

            imageviewRating2 = [UIImageView new];
            [rate addSubview:imageviewRating2];
            imageviewRating2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [imageviewRating2 sizeToFit];

            imageviewRating3 = [UIImageView new];
            [rate addSubview:imageviewRating3];
            imageviewRating3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [imageviewRating3 sizeToFit];

            imageviewRating4 = [UIImageView new];
            [rate addSubview:imageviewRating4];
            imageviewRating4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [imageviewRating4 sizeToFit];

            imageviewRating5 = [UIImageView new];
            [rate addSubview:imageviewRating5];
            imageviewRating5.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            [imageviewRating5 sizeToFit];


            UIImage *imageStarDisabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
            //UIImage *imageStarEnabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2.png"];


            imageviewRating1.image = imageStarDisabled;
            imageviewRating2.image = imageStarDisabled;
            imageviewRating3.image = imageStarDisabled;
            imageviewRating4.image = imageStarDisabled;
            imageviewRating5.image = imageStarDisabled;





            }

            return self;
        }

        - (void)layoutSubviews
        {
            [super layoutSubviews];

            // Make sure the contentView does a layout pass here so that its subviews have their frames set, which we
            // need to use to set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth below.
            [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

            // Set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth of the mutli-line bodyLabel based on the evaluated width of the label's frame,
            // as this will allow the text to wrap correctly, and as a result allow the label to take on the correct height.
            self.labelTitle.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.labelTitle.frame);
        }

        - (void)updateConstraints {
            [super updateConstraints];

            if (self.didSetupConstraints) return;


            //UIImage *imageStarDisabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
            UIImage *imageStarEnabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2.png"];

            if(rating > 0){

            for(int i = 1; i < rating + 1; i++){

                if(i == 1){
                imageviewRating1.image = imageStarEnabled;
                }

                if (i == 2) {
                imageviewRating2.image = imageStarEnabled;
                }

                if (i == 3) {
                imageviewRating3.image = imageStarEnabled;
                }

                if (i == 4) {
                imageviewRating4.image = imageStarEnabled;
                }

                if (i == 5) {
                imageviewRating5.image = imageStarEnabled;
                }


            }

            }




            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary7 = @{@"main":main};
            NSArray *constraint_H37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[main]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary7];

            NSArray *constraint_V37 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[main]|"
                                          options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary7];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_H37];
            [self.contentView addConstraints:constraint_V37];


            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary3 = @{@"top":top,@"center":center,@"bottom":bottom};
            NSArray *constraint_H3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[top]-5-[center]-5-[bottom]-10-|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H33 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[top]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H333 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[center]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSArray *constraint_H3335657 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bottom]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary3];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary4 = @{@"labelUser":labelUser,@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelUser]|"
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary45 = @{@"labelDate":labelDate};
            NSArray *constraint_H4555 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelDate]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary45];

            NSArray *constraint_H44 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelUser]-20-[labelDate]-5-|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary4];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary48 = @{@"labelTitle":labelTitle,@"imageviewThreadImage":imageviewThreadImage};
            NSArray *constraint_H48 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[labelTitle]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary48];

            NSArray *constraint_H48342 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                            views:viewsDictionary48];

            NSArray *constraint_H448 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[imageviewThreadImage(36)]-5-[labelTitle]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary48];

            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary488 = @{@"labelCat":labelCat,@"labelCountry":labelCountry,@"labelSubCat":labelSubCat,@"rate":rate};
            NSArray *constraint_H488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCat]|"
                                              options:0
                                              metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelCountry]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                               views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898fgf54 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[labelSubCat]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary488];
            NSArray *constraint_H48898fgf54fdf = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[rate]|"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary488];

            NSArray *constraint_H4488 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[labelCat]-10-[labelSubCat]-10-[labelCountry]-10-[rate]"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary488];




            NSDictionary *viewsDictionary4885 = @{@"imageviewRating1":imageviewRating1,@"imageviewRating2":imageviewRating2,@"imageviewRating3":imageviewRating3,@"imageviewRating4":imageviewRating4,@"imageviewRating5":imageviewRating5};

            NSArray *constraint_H488fbfb = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageviewRating1(15)]|"
                                               options:0
                                               metrics:nil
                                             views:viewsDictionary4885];

            NSArray *constraint_H48898xfb = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageviewRating2(15)]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary4885];

            NSArray *constraint_H48898xfbfg = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageviewRating3(15)]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary4885];

            NSArray *constraint_H48898xfbxfg = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageviewRating4(15)]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary4885];

            NSArray *constraint_H48898xfrtbxfg = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[imageviewRating5(15)]|"
                                                options:0
                                                metrics:nil
                                                  views:viewsDictionary4885];

            NSArray *constraint_H48898fgf54fxb = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imageviewRating1(15)]-2-[imageviewRating2(15)]-2-[imageviewRating3(15)]-2-[imageviewRating4(15)]-2-[imageviewRating5(15)]"
                                                  options:0
                                                  metrics:nil
                                                views:viewsDictionary4885];




            [main addConstraints:constraint_H3];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H33];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H333];
            [top addConstraints:constraint_H4];
            [top addConstraints:constraint_H44];
            [center addConstraints:constraint_H48];
            [center addConstraints:constraint_H448];
            [top addConstraints:constraint_H4555];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H3335657];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H488];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H4488];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H48898];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H48342];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H48898fgf54];
            [main addConstraints:constraint_H48898fgf54fdf];

            [bottom addConstraints:constraint_H488fbfb];
            [bottom addConstraints:constraint_H48898xfb];
            [bottom addConstraints:constraint_H48898xfbfg];
            [bottom addConstraints:constraint_H48898xfbxfg];
            [bottom addConstraints:constraint_H48898xfrtbxfg];
            [bottom addConstraints:constraint_H48898fgf54fxb];



            self.didSetupConstraints = YES;

        }


        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            // Initialization code



        }

        - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
            [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        @end
```

ViewController that sets the rating from the Database:

```
        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        // 3) Load picker in background
            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{


            NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"threadTitle=%@&threadCountry=%@&threadCategory=%@&threadSubCategory=%@",searchThreadTitleTopThreads, searchThreadCountryTopThreads, searchThreadCategoryTopThreads, searchThreadSubCategoryTopThreads];
            __block NSString *response = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestString :@"xxx.php"];


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                if(response.length > 0){

                    NSDictionary *dic = [response JSONValue];

                    if((NSNull*)dic != [NSNull null]){
                        int at_ID = 0;
                        int at_U_ID = 0;
                        int rating = 0;
                        NSString *at_Title;
                        NSString *at_Desc;
                        NSString *at_Cat;
                        NSString *at_SubCat;
                        NSString *at_Date;
                        NSString *at_Country;
                        NSString *at_FirstName;
                        NSString *at_LastName;
                        for(NSDictionary *dict in dic)
                        {
                            counter = counter + 1;
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"AT_ID"] intValue];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_U_ID"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_U_ID = [[dict objectForKey:@"AT_U_ID"] intValue];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_Title"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_Title = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_Title"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_Desc"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_Desc = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_Desc"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_Cat"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_Cat = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_Cat"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_SubCat"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_SubCat = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_SubCat"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_Country"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_Country = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_Country"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"U_FirstName"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_FirstName = [dict objectForKey:@"U_FirstName"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"U_LastName"] != [NSNull null]){
                                at_LastName = [dict objectForKey:@"U_LastName"];
                            }
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AVG(r.TR_Value)"] != [NSNull null]){
                                rating = [[dict objectForKey:@"AVG(r.TR_Value)"] intValue];
                            }
                            NSString *dateTS = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_Date"];
                            if((NSNull *)[dict objectForKey:@"AT_Date2"] != [NSNull null]){
                                NSString *timestampString = [dict objectForKey:@"AT_Date2"];
                                double timestampDate = [timestampString doubleValue];
                                NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timestampDate];
                                NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                                [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
                                at_Date = [_formatter stringFromDate:d];
                                if (counter == 1) {
                                    //lastDateForumActivity = dateTS;
                                }
                            }
                            if(counter == 1){
                                //lastDateForumActivity = dateTS;
                            }
                            Thread *thread = [[Thread alloc] init];
                            thread.tag = at_ID;
                            thread.idUser = at_U_ID;
                            thread.firstname = at_FirstName;
                            thread.lastname = at_LastName;
                            thread.idThread = at_ID;
                            thread.title = at_Title;
                            thread.desc = at_Desc;
                            thread.cat = at_Cat;
                            thread.date = at_Date;
                            thread.country = at_Country;
                            thread.subcat = at_SubCat;
                            thread.rating = rating; //RATING SET
                            [tmpArray4 addObject:thread];

                            //cell = nil;

                        }

                        at_ID = 0;
                        at_U_ID = 0;
                        at_Title = @"";
                        at_Desc = @"";
                        at_Cat = @"";
                        at_Date = @"";
                        at_Country = @"";
                        at_FirstName = @"";
                        at_LastName = @"";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Update your question with your `cellForRowAtIndexPathMethod`.

Comment: Show the code of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and the custom UITableViewCell implementation and how you set it. Since there is the reuse for UITableViewCell, my guess is that your issue is there.

Comment: Cells get recycled when they scroll out of view.

Comment: Show the setRating: method

Comment: Your custom cell needs to properly update the image views of the stars when the rating is updated. You only have logic to enable stars but not to disable stars.

Comment: And why is the logic to update the image views with the enabled stars inside the `updateConstraints` method and not in the `setRating:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy, becuase its in updatecontraints, when i set the rating in cellforrowindexpath its to late when setting in init method of cell

Comment: @rmaddy, im disabling stars in init initialy then in updatecontraints im updating only the stars that are enabled via the rating.

Comment: @redoc01: But the init of the cell isn't always called. Check when it's done called. In your loop for "enabling" the stars, "disable" also the unwanted one.

Comment: @Larme, how do you mean

Comment: @Larme, ah ok, let me try

Comment: Also, when you correct it (see my answer below), I would change your title to reflect that the issue is with cell reuse, not a problem with state persistence of an int variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is that you don't account for the cells being reused.  Because the cells are reused, the initialization of the cells set the image to your disabled stars, but in your code to set the stars correctly, you only toggle them to the enabled star image.  You never set them back if the current cell's rating is 0, but it is being applied to a reused cell that had a rating of 3.  So your code will not change any of the images, so the 3 enabled star images will remain.

Add a setter for the rating property with something like this.  Also, as of Xcode 4.4 or so, @synthesize isn't needed, so you can get rid of that.

```
- (void)setRating: (int)newRatingValue {
        _rating = newRatingValue;

        UIImage *imageStarDisabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
        UIImage *imageStarEnabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2.png"];

        imageviewRating1.image = rating >= 1 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating2.image = rating >= 2 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating3.image = rating >= 3 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating4.image = rating >= 4 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating5.image = rating >= 5 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
```

}

I believe the below will work, although if you're updating the rating on the background thread, it may cause some problems.  You may need to wrapp the updating of the images in a dispatch async call to execute it on the main (UI) thread like so:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        imageviewRating1.image = rating >= 1 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating2.image = rating >= 2 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating3.image = rating >= 3 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating4.image = rating >= 4 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
        imageviewRating5.image = rating >= 5 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
});`
```

Also, you should learn how to use the debugger to put breakpoints and step through your code, inspecting the state of things.  It will go a long way to helping to troubleshoot and diagnose these types of issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I moved your logic here and worked @wottle:

```
if(tableView == tableViewTopThreads){

            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

            ThreadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            //cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
            //cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[ThreadTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            }

            Thread *t = (Thread*)[tmpArray4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.labelTitle.text = t.title;
            cell.labelCat.text = t.cat;
            cell.labelUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", t.firstname, t.lastname];
            cell.labelDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", t.date];
            cell.labelCountry.text = t.country;
            cell.labelSubCat.text = t.subcat;
            cell.rating = t.rating;

            UIImage *imageStarDisabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
            UIImage *imageStarEnabled = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2.png"];

            cell.imageviewRating1.image = t.rating >= 1 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
            cell.imageviewRating2.image = t.rating >= 2 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
            cell.imageviewRating3.image = t.rating >= 3 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
            cell.imageviewRating4.image = t.rating >= 4 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;
            cell.imageviewRating5.image = t.rating >= 5 ? imageStarEnabled : imageStarDisabled;

            [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
            [cell.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell.contentView setNeedsLayout];
            [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

            return cell;
            }
```

Is this the best place to put the logic?

Comment: I wouldn't put it there.  It will work, but it should be the cells responsibility to update the images when the rating changes.  Doing it there could result in other code changing the rating, and then the underlying rating won't be reflected by the star images. I update my answer to provide more guidance.